# How to add data from jTable to JSON file

Tags: openstreetmap, geojson, java, json, imposm

I want to create a tools that add my selected item to the JSON file in java netbeanse;

for this I make a ComboBox for selecting my item , and also I have a jTable for display the ArrayList of selected item, and the items in jTable is add/remove by clicking on [add/delete] Button from combobox list item.

So my question is how to add my selected items which is display in jTable into json file. and if I delete item form the jTable it is also delete on JSON file.
finally I need the json file with my selected items,
you can see the schema of my json file in below:

Do you have any idea about this.

[image]

Adding:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
int row1 = jTable1.getModel().getRowCount();
model.addRow(new Object[]{row1+1,jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()});
jTable1.setModel(model);
```

Deleting:

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

 int row = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
 if(jTable1.getRowCount()>0){
 DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
 model.removeRow(row);
};
```

JSON file:

```
{
    "tags": {
        "load_all": true,
        "exclude": [
            "created_by",
            "source"
        ]
    },
    "use_single_id_space": true,
    "tables": {
        "all": {
            "fields": [
                {
                    "type": "id",
                    "name": "osm_id",
                    "key": null
                },
                {
                    "type": "geometry",
                    "name": "geometry",
                    "key": null
                },
                {
                    "type": "hstore_tags",
                    "name": "tags",
                    "key": null
                }
            ],
            "type": "geometry",
            "type_mappings": {
                "points": {
                     "Item 1": ["__any__"],
                     "Item 2": ["__any__"]

                },
                "linestrings": {
                     "Item 1": ["__any__"],
                     "Item 2": ["__any__"]
                },
                "polygons": {
                     "Item 1": ["__any__"],
                     "Item 2": ["__any__"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what are you using to generate the JSON? normally there is some java model that gets converted

Comment: it is possible to user some library like json.sample https://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/                          but i want to generate this code by connecting it to the value of table